# Can the tags "web" and "website" be blacklisted?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

[web](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) and [websites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites) don't add any value. This site is about websites and the internet, so practically every on topic question could be tagged with those two tags. I've been discussing getting rid of those tags on the chat, and not that I'm back from vacation I thought that I would make an actual feature request on the meta about it.

Comment: Also, can we do the same with the [tag:sites] tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tags have been burninated.

*And* blacklisted.

Both seem like rather obvious tags that would apply to most - if not all - questions on the site, so they've been marked as "intrinsic" - this allows the migration of questions with these tags, but strips them as they come in.

**Please, [care for the widows and orphans](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged).**

Comment: Widows and orphans - they are no more.

Comment: Can we also get rid of the sites tag: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/862/tag-sites-please-set-as-intrinsic-blacklist 

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I agree. I'm sure if we go through those they can be safely removed. I did a bunch a month or two ago and I don't see why we don't just finish up the remaining ~65. I'm sure those questions could use a good cleanup anyway.