# Tag: sites - please set as intrinsic/"blacklist"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Following on [request to remove websites tag](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/857/can-the-tags-web-and-website-be-blacklisted), (synonym: [web-sites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-sites)) please remove [sites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burninated, and blacklisted.

Since I can't find any questions migrated in with this tag, I've opted not to make it an intrinsic tag.